# Print array in Codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter, datatables, codeigniter-3

Sorry if the questions seams stupid but I have created an array in my controller and I pass it to the view with the $data['sample'] array.

Here is my MYSQL Query:

```
SELECT  workplace.id, workplace.type,
    MAX(IF(workplace.region_id = 1, workplace.name,0)) 'Dhaka South',
    MAX(IF(workplace.region_id = 2, workplace.name,0)) 'Dhaka North',
    MAX(IF(workplace.region_id = 3, workplace.name,0)) 'Savar',
    MAX(IF(workplace.region_id = 4, workplace.name,0)) 'Narayangonjh',
    MAX(IF(workplace.region_id = 5, workplace.name,0)) 'Mymensingh',
    MAX(IF(workplace.region_id = 6, workplace.name,0)) 'Barisal',
    MAX(IF(workplace.region_id = 7, workplace.name,0)) 'Faridpur',
    MAX(IF(workplace.region_id = 8, workplace.name,0)) 'Jessore'
FROM    workplace
WHERE   workplace.type='area'
GROUP BY workplace.id
```

If f print_r the sample it looks like

```
SELECT workplace.id, workplace.type, MAX(IF(workplace.region_id = 1, workplace.name,0)) 'Dhaka South', MAX(IF(workplace.region_id = 2, workplace.name,0)) 'Dhaka North', MAX(IF(workplace.region_id = 3, workplace.name,0)) 'Savar', MAX(IF(workplace.region_id = 4, workplace.name,0)) 'Narayangonjh', WHERE workplace.type='area' GROUP BY workplace.id
```

> Array
>   (
>       [0] => stdClass Object
>           (
>               [id] => 15
>               [type] => area
>               [Dhaka South] => Jatrabari
>               [Dhaka North] => 0
>               [Savar] => 0
>               [Narayangonjh] => 0
>               [Mymensingh] => 0
>               [Barisal] => 0
>               [Faridpur] => 0
>               [Jessore] => 0
>           )

```
[1] => stdClass Object
    (
        [id] => 16
        [type] => area
        [Dhaka South] => Lalbag
        [Dhaka North] => 0
        [Savar] => 0
        [Narayangonjh] => 0
        [Mymensingh] => 0
        [Barisal] => 0
        [Faridpur] => 0
        [Jessore] => 0
    )

[2] => stdClass Object
    (
        [id] => 17
        [type] => area
        [Dhaka South] => Dhanmondi
        [Dhaka North] => 0
        [Savar] => 0
        [Narayangonjh] => 0
        [Mymensingh] => 0
        [Barisal] => 0
        [Faridpur] => 0
        [Jessore] => 0
    )

[3] => stdClass Object
    (
        [id] => 18
        [type] => area
        [Dhaka South] => 0
        [Dhaka North] => Gulshan
        [Savar] => 0
        [Narayangonjh] => 0
        [Mymensingh] => 0
        [Barisal] => 0
        [Faridpur] => 0
        [Jessore] => 0
    )
```

I want to use these data in a datatable where id,type,Dhaka South,Dhaka North,Savar,Narayangonjh,Mymensingh,Barisal,Faridpur,Jessore will be in thead as heading and values in tbody as value.
Please help if you can.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

May this help you

controller

```
$data['persons'] = '' // obj your query result
```

view

```
<?php 
     $arrKey = array();
     foreach ($persons[0] as $key => $person):
        $arrKey[] = $key;
     endforeach ?>
     <table>
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <?php foreach ($arrKey as $akey): ?>
                    <td><?php echo $akey; ?></td>
                <?php endforeach ?>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
                <?php foreach ($persons as $key => $person): ?>
                    <tr>
                        <?php foreach ($arrKey as $akey): ?>
                            <td><?php echo $person->$akey; ?></td>
                        <?php endforeach ?>     
                    </tr>
                <?php endforeach ?>
        </tbody>
     </table>
```

Answer (score 0):

Do like this

```
$data['sample'] = $your_array;

//Getting column names here
foreach ($data['sample'] as $key){
    $data['column_names'] = array_keys((array) $key);
    break;
}
$this->load->view('file', $data);
```

**View**

```
<table id="example" class="table table-striped table-bordered" style="width:100%">
<thead>
    <tr><!-- Showing column names here -->
        <?php foreach($column_names as $column){ 
            echo $column;
        ?>
    </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
    <?php foreach($sample as $row){?>
    <tr>
        <td><?= $row->id ?> </td>
        <td><?= $row->type ?> </td>
        <td><?= $row->Dhaka Soutd ?> </td>
        <td><?= $row->Dhaka Nortd ?> </td>
        <td><?= $row->Savar ?> </td>
        <td><?= $row->Narayangonjh ?> </td>
        <td><?= $row->Mymensingh ?> </td>
        <td><?= $row->Barisal ?> </td>
        <td><?= $row->Faridpur ?> </td>
        <td><?= $row->Jessore ?> </td>

    </tr>
    <?php } ?>
</tbody>
```

Comment: But I need the header dynamic as the array key because it may change

Comment: Hi @Danish.Ali thanks for your answer, but in the table body, I will not be able to know $row value. So "$row->Dhaka South" is also has to be dynamic. actually I am bringing this data by converting columns into rows(SQL pivot). 

Hope you understand my bad English communication

Comment: SELECT  workplace.id, workplace.type,
MAX(IF(workplace.region_id = 1, workplace.name,0)) 'Dhaka South',
MAX(IF(workplace.region_id = 2, workplace.name,0)) 'Dhaka North',
MAX(IF(workplace.region_id = 3, workplace.name,0)) 'Savar',
MAX(IF(workplace.region_id = 4, workplace.name,0)) 'Narayangonjh',
WHERE   workplace.type='area'
GROUP BY workplace.id

Here is my code for your better understanding

Comment: Add this query in your question.

Comment: use isset($row->Dhaka Soutd) ? $row->Dhaka Soutd : '';